# Is there a way to perform a case insensitive sort to a std::deque<std::pair<std::string,std::string>> files?

Tags: c++, algorithm, sorting, stl

```
std::deque<std::pair<std::string, std::string>> mFiles;
```

I have tried a few compare classes without any luck. eg-> the following lambda:

```
sort(mFiles.begin(), mFiles.end(), [](std::pair<string, string> a, std::pair<string, string> b) {
        //code to ignore case during comparison
        return a<b;
        });
```

I'm using the following code to sort using the first element of the std::pair:

```
std::sort(mFiles.begin(), mFiles.end());
```

Comment: what *"compare classes"* you have tried?

Comment: Are you aware that `toupper(a[0]), toupper(b[0]);` are effectively no-ops? 1. It's done on the resp. first char of each string only. 2. `toupper()` is a function (or a function-like macro) which doesn't modify the character in place - you have to assign the result. [toupper()](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/toupper)